# Paw App and Google Drive OAuth Error: OAuth 2 parameters can only have a single value: client_id

Tags: ios, swift, google-authentication, paw-app

I am attempting to set up Paw to play with Google Drive integration. I have Auth working fine in my iOS Swift app utilizing the SFAuthentificationSession service for this, but  I would like to utilize Paw to test different use cases.  Any suggestions on how to set this up?

Thanks!

Mark

Answer (score 0):

My issue was I was using the iOS credentials which does not contain a client secret.  I created new credentials as a web based interface and it works without a charm.